# Performance issues in android

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

Hai I'm developing an android app that contains many fragments, Recyclerviews, Layout.
My app's performance was very poor. Suggest me a correct way to use the Recylerview, Fragments and activities.
Assume that my recycler view is a timeline like in instagram/facebook. So i have so many onClickListeners, image loading(I used Glide), and some calculations(basic calculations like Time, simple loops...) and few function calls.
I have implemented onViewRecycled() and in that, I have unset all the listeners and freed the loaded images using Glide.clear(img).
When I used the profiler to lookup the memory usage, it shows >1 GB in android 6.0 devices and >250 MB in android 7.0  devices.
And I'm loading images and text data from the Firebase Firestore.
My problem is even after doing all those things, the performance of my app is very low.

So please help me to improve my app's performance.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered multithreading? This is a very broad question.

Comment: Use pagination or lazy loading..

Comment: sorry :-(. But I don't know where to ask these question. And I don't know any android experts.

Comment: @TheWanderer yes I have used AsyncTask some places

Comment: You need to use it in more places. Consider using RxJava/RxAndroid, which is much more powerful and user-friendly.

Comment: Load the Bitmaps with a small scale to save memory

Answer (score 0):

Use Loaders! A background thread started by doInBackground(Params…params) will not be destroyed along with Activity Lifecycle onStop() or onDestroy(). And an attempt of modifying activity state on basis of it’s result can cause in crash! It takes up your memory when doInBackground again and again. Or else you can implement Volley or retrofit for network call etc.